# Как изменить размер видео в соответствии с размером виджета?

Tags: python, opencv, ui

```
        self.timer = QTimer()  # Таймер для камеры
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.camera_on)  # Подключаем камеру
        self.ui.Camera_btn.clicked.connect(self.control_timer)  # Визуализация включение камеры

    def camera_on(self):
        ret, image = self.cap.read()
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # get image infos
        height, width, channel = image.shape
        step = channel * width
        # create QImage from image
        img = QImage(image.data, width, height, step, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        # show image in img_label
        self.ui.Cam.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))

    def control_timer(self):
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
            self.timer.start(0)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть виджет, отрисованный в UI Designer, при этом растянутый на весь экран. Как привязать этот виджет к камере, чтобы она стала по его размерам?(на фото форма с камерой, которую нужно изменить до размера виджета) [image: Форма с камерой] Код выше- то, из чего состоит камера.
Спасибо за ответы, каждый ответ будет оценен по достоинству

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался, необходимо было использовать функцию  '''self.ui.Cam.setScaledContents(True)'''